# When to use determiners after a preposition?

Tags: prepositions, determiners

As far as I know, while using a countable noun you should put a determiner before the countable noun. But some examples confused me.

> ***A*** type ***of*** metal button ("button" is a countable noun)
>
> ***A*** case ***of*** bee sting ("sting" is a countable noun)
>
> Determine ***a*** type ***of a*** lesion
>
> There was ***the*** case ***of*** ***a*** landlord vs tenant.

Why we don't use a determiner before the nouns in the first two examples; however, we use a determiner before the nouns in the last two examples ? When don't I have to use a determiner before countable nouns ?

Answer (score 1):

See, this is one of those things a native speaker just *knows* but might not be able to articulate, but I'm going to give it a go.

> A type of metal button

Here, there is no metal button (well, there probably is, but the button itself isn't relevant). "Metal button" is acting as a **common noun**, a noun that refers to a class of things. Such nouns are generally used in the singular and don't get articles or determiners more generally. Technically, of course, *button* is the noun and *metal* an adjective, but they work together as a *noun phrase* filling the role of common noun.

Note that a noun being a common noun is a matter of usage, not inherent to the word itself. "The type of this metal button" is no longer a common noun usage, because there's an actual physical and specific metal button.

> A case of bee sting

Again, bee sting is a common noun, a class of thing. In both of these examples, another noun is the 'main' noun of the clause - *type* and *case*, respectively. In both cases, the *of*-phrase refines that main noun. It is, you might say, a property of that main noun.

> There was the case of a landlord vs tenant

This is a little broken, because tenant should get a determiner as well, or be plural. The sentence also works without either of them, with a subtly different meaning. "The case of a landlord vs their tenant" means you are talking about a specific case in which a landlord was facing their tenant, presumably in a legal action. "The case of landlord vs tenant" would refer to a **category** of cases, even though *case* is singular here (for complex reasons not relevant to this question - it wouldn't work for all other words that might be in place of *case*).

> Determine a type of a lesion

This one is also broken; a given lesion will generally only have one type, so it ought to be "determine the type of a lesion". This is an instruction to determine the type of a lesion. It might be a specific lesion, or it might be telling you to find some lesion somewhere and determine its type, but in either case the action would involve an actual specific lesion.

In these later cases, where there is an article on *landlord* or *lesion*, there is, at least conceptually, a specific lesion or landlord involved. *Lesion* and *landlord* are not referring to their respective categories, but to actual concrete items.